# How to set reply-to-email-address for transactional emails in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2.4, transactional-mail

We would like to use a custom mailbox for all transactional emails sent by the store. Sometimes a customer replies to f.e. an order confirmation email and this email then also is sent to this mailbox. 
As this mailbox is not checked regularly we would like to add a reply-to-email to all transactional emails. This is not possible out-of-the-box in Magento 2.4. Is there a solution how to add it programmatically to all transactional emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a reply-to email address programmatically for all transactional emails in Magento 2.4, you can create a custom module to extend the email functionality. Follow these steps to create the module:

Create a new folder for the custom module in app/code. Name it according to your company name and module name, such as CompanyName/CustomReplyTo.

In the new module folder, create these subdirectories: etc and Plugin.

Create a module.xml file in the etc directory and add the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="CompanyName_CustomReplyTo" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Email"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Create a di.xml file in the etc directory and add the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder">
        <plugin name="customReplyToPlugin" type="CompanyName\CustomReplyTo\Plugin\TransportBuilderPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a TransportBuilderPlugin.php file in the Plugin directory and add the following content:

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\CustomReplyTo\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

class TransportBuilderPlugin
{
    public function aroundSetTemplateVars(
        TransportBuilder $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        array $templateVars
    ) {
        // Set the custom reply-to email address.
        $replyToEmail = 'your_reply_to_email@example.com';
        if ($replyToEmail) {
            $subject->setReplyTo($replyToEmail);
        }
        return $proceed($templateVars);
    }
}
```

Replace 'your_reply_to_email@example.com' with your desired reply-to email address.

Enable the module by running the following command in your Magento root directory:

```
bin/magento module:enable CompanyName_CustomReplyTo
```

Update the Magento system: (Keep Calm)

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean
```

After completing these steps, your custom module should be installed and active. It will automatically set the reply-to email address for all transactional emails sent by your Magento store.

Comment: Many thanks, awesome! works like a charm!